# Html Table: When <tr> is Overflown, Send <td> To The Bottom

Tags: html

I am wondering if is it possible to have overflown `<tr>` and send the `<td>` to the bottom of the other `<td>` inside the `<tr>`.

So for example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Header1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to have content 2 exactly bellow Content 1 without assigning it into a new `<tr>`? Or something like a `<tr>` inside a `<tr>`

Comment: Short answer is **no**. Long answer `tr` is a row, a single line of `td` or `th` elements. The **only** valid children of a `tr` is `td` or `th`. You can create a table in a `td` but chances are you shouldn't.

Comment: Keep in mind `table` is for tabular data only. If you are using it for anything else you are using it incorrectly. Perhaps look as [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) instead

Comment: In theory <td>Content 1<br>Content 2</td> can work like this ;-) But there will be still single row.